# C# Unity DI container not accepting Enum with RegisterType function

Tags: c#

### see this below code

```
    cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.local);
    cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.remote);
    cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.OrcsWeb);
    cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.Sage);
```

Unity **RegisterType** not accepting **enum** but when if i pass string then no problem occur but i have to use **enum**. my full code as follow. so some one see my code and tell me what and where to fix in code as a result **enum** should be accepted.

### full code

```
public enum ConType { local, remote, OrcsWeb, Sage, };

public interface IBBAConnection
{
    IDbConnection  GetConnection();
    string ConType { get; set; }
}

public class BBAConnection : IBBAConnection
{
    public ConType ConType { get; set; }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string _connectionString = "";
        IDbConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            // inside if else logic we fetch connection string from ini file or from any source and inistialize connection.
            if (ConType == ConType.local)
            {
                _connectionString = "put here local db connection";
                connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            }
            else if (ConType == ConType.remote)
            {
                _connectionString = "put here remote db connection";
                connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            }
            else if (ConType == ConType.OrcsWeb)
            {
                _connectionString = "put here website db connection";
                connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            }
            else if (ConType == ConType.Sage)
            {
                _connectionString = "put here sage connection";
                connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            }

            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strErr = ex.Message;
        }

        return connection;
    }
}

public static class Factory
{
    static IUnityContainer cont = null;

    public static IBBAConnection initialize(ConType oConType)
    {
        IBBAConnection oDbConnection = null;

        cont = new UnityContainer();
        cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.local);
        cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.remote);
        cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.OrcsWeb);
        cont.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>(ConType.Sage);

        oDbConnection = cont.Resolve<IBBAConnection>(oConType);
        //oDbConnection.ConType = type;

        return oDbConnection;
    }
}
```

looking for guide line that what to change as a result **Enum** should be accepted.

Comment: I would actually register a config with unity, each config can be the local, remote, sage etc... and then in the constructor of `BBAConnection` I would pull this config in. That way you don't need to do if statements

Comment: sorry not very clear without config how to do it in code........share idea if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I think you should do.

It will dramatically reduce the complexity of `BBAConnection` because you're letting your `IConnectionConfig` binding determine the connection string you need.

```
public interface IConnectionConfig
{
    string GetConnectionString();
}

public class LocalConnectionConfig : IConnectionConfig
{
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return "db connection for local";
    }
}

public class BBAConnection : IBBAConnection 
{ 
    private readonly IConnectionConfig config;

    public BBAConnection(IConnectionConfig config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string _connectionString = "";
        IDbConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(this.config.GetConnectionString());

            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strErr = ex.Message;
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

The registrations:

```
container.RegisterType<IBBAConnection, BBAConnection>();
container.RegisterType<IConnectionConfig, LocalConnectionConfig>();
```

### Conceptually Speaking

You would normally let your build configurations define what configs you are using. You can then use that in your code to define which config you need.

Comment: i have to use enum as per specs

Comment: are these company specs, or college(university) specs?

Comment: as per code review it is manager decision that we need to use enum with unity!

Comment: I would seriously tell him to reconsider. Using enums in conjunction with a switch/if statements break open closed principle, and you are breaking single responsibility pattern as well. Plus, like you are discovering - is really difficult to do through DI - so why not take the more powerful and easy route...

Comment: Your manager is fallible and also should probably not be making technical decisions like this unless there is a reason to interop with other systems. If you absolutely must do this you can use `InjectionFactory` from unity to manually inject the enum. We do this, and I wouldn't recommend it. It is very brittle.

Comment: i believe there must be some way out to use `Enum with RegisterType`

Comment: I just said - you can use `InjectionFactory` in conjunction with `RegisterType` to do this. But I would not recommend it.

Comment: Like @DanPantry says you start down the route of factories. Just remember if you use a factory never change the constructor of your `BBAConnection` because your DI will stop working

Comment: sorry i am not getting a simple example where InjectionFactory has been used with enum.........can u get me one if possible. thanks

Comment: I've been looking through the documentation and I can tell you that it is a deep dark road. I can't find an explicit answer on this, and it seems like enums were left out of constructor injection. I strongly feel that you will not get the answer you want because it really painful to achieve what you are doing. The problem you are having is that you aren't using DI properly. If you work with DI you'll find everything really simple, but because you are fighting it - things are a lot more difficult